# NSClient++, what is the best way to monitor SQL Server Agent jobs?

Tags: nagios, icinga, nsclient++

What is the best way to monitor SQL Server Agent jobs using NSClient++ (and Icinga)? We have about 100 jobs on the server.

It would be nice if monitoring would be able to handle recovery state per each job also.

Comment: I'm not going to attempt a full answer as my MSSQL is ridiculously rusty, but I know that SQL Agent jobs store their info/history in the msdb database. Maybe this pushes you a little closer to the path you need to follow to a full-blown answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [SQL Server sub-category](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/SQLServer) on Nagios Exchange that may help you. There's a [job monitoring plugin](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/SQLServer/MSSQL-Job-Monitoring/details), for example.

It doesn't involve NSClient++, but there may be some functionality in [check_mssql_health](http://labs.consol.de/lang/en/nagios/check_mssql_health/) that could help you. If not, you can use it to run user-defined SQL statements (see --mode=sql).

If you don't want to expose SQL Server to Nagios over the network, or *need* to go through NSClient++ for some other reason, you'll have to find/write something that runs locally (vbscript, python, etc.) and use the [CheckExternalScripts](http://www.nsclient.org/nscp/wiki/CheckExternalScripts) handler.

Comment: I have surfed to https://github.com/jetole/MSSQL-Job-History, what is something I was looking for. Thank you very much.